# Error occurred during initialization of Java VM

Tags: debian, java

Trying to install JDK 1.8 to 32 bit Debian Squeeze machine. I have extracted `jdk-8u171-linux-i586.tar.gz` to `/opt` folder and ave exported `JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_171"`

I got error below while run Java:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load ZIP library: /opt/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
```

What java is trying to tell me? Does it means it don't see it's libraries? How to fix this problem?

I have the same type hardware with same OS that runs the same java version fine, but I don't know how it was installed.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately  java-package is not available for Squeeze

Comment: I the file present? Is it in the load path? Have you tried to set the JAVA_HOME to `/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/`?